# Cannot upgrade to 20.04.1

Tags: upgrade

So I went to check for some updates using the Software Updater and it tells me that my current version (19.04) can no longer receive updates and therefore I need to upgrade to 20.04.1. So I update it, plug in my password, and after a few seconds it tells me that "upgrade from disco to focal is not supported with this tool"

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04's upgrade path was to 19.10 (ie. the next release), however given 19.10 is now EOL, I'd recommend *upgrade via re-install* (you didn't say if desktop or server; it's easier with desktop without user data being erased [unless you format!] and additional packages auto-installed [if available in Ubuntu repositories for new release]... but use a LTS release in future if you don't want to *release-upgrade* every 6-9 months.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: FYI:   Ubuntu has two upgrade paths; from one release to the next (ie. 19.04 to 19.10, from 19.10 to 20.04 etc), or from a LTS to the next LTS (ie. 18.04 LTS to 20.04.1 LTS; this opens after the .1 has been released).  19.04 was **not** a LTS so was the every-release path. The automatic upgrade tool was designed to be used before 19.10 reached EOL; if your architecture is i386 though - 19.04/disco is the *end-of-the-line* and you should return to 18.04/bionic.

Answer (score 1):

When you originally installed Ubuntu 19.04, the download page offered you two choices: 18.04 LTS and 19.04.

- Both choices were clearly explained, including that 19.04 was supported for only nine months.
- On an unmodified, stock Ubuntu system, the Update Notifier applet nags the user to release-upgrade when the next release of Ubuntu becomes available. Some folks do not remember disabling (or haywiring around) this useful feature. Update Notifier is well tested in every supported release of Ubuntu -- it works.

Upgrades from 19.04 to 19.10 were available October 2019 - January 2020. Folks who use Standard (non-LTS) releases of Ubuntu mark their calendars every April and October.

- You waited too long: We do not provide support for release-upgrading from one EOL release of Ubuntu to another EOL release of Ubuntu.
- The only supported method available to you is to back up your data and clean-install a supported release of Ubuntu.
- You can do anything *unsupported* that you wish; it's your system. But we obviously won't provide support for it.